# Webpack - Source Maps not working

Tags: webpack, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I'm new to webpack and I can't seem to get it configure to produce source maps. This is my webpack.config.js file:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    devTool: "#source-map",
    debug: true,
    entry: ['webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src'
    ],
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port:8080
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        moduleDirectories: ['../node_modules', 'src'],
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
};
```

I've tried setting devTool to "eval-source-map", "inline-source-map", etc but no luck.

Chrome dev tools not showing any source maps:

[image]

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rcj-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "lodash": "^4.2.1",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you running webpack using `webpack -d` in the terminal? It might be the same as the `debug: true` option you have in the config though. Other than that, it looks fine to me. Do you get any output message for generating a `bundle.js.map` file? If so, check that sourcemaps are enabled in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webpack config parameter is spelled [`devtool`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/), not `devTool`.

So `devTool: "#source-map"` should be `devtool: "#source-map"`.

Comment: Nice catch - I didn't notice.